# Possible to treat singular Javascript var as an array?

Tags: javascript

Whilst I am sure there's a duplicate question of this out there, because I am unfamiliar with javascript, I don't know the proper term, and thus wouldn't know where to start searching for it (if I knew what it was called, I'd just read up about it).

I have a singular var (that is **not** an array) that contains a set of numbers:

```
var Latitude = Math.floor(Math.random()*90) + Math.random();
```

I want to encode all numbers contained in Latitude, including the numbers after the floating point (and including the floating point, and any minus signs - although note this code example doesn't add a minus sign) into an array of letters, so 0 = A, 1 = B, so on.

Is there any *simple* way of converting the singular var into an array of individual numbers for encoding?

Comment: You mean print the number/convert the number to text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, slight typo in your question, `Math.random` is a function. You want to convert the number you get to a string, the easiest way to do this is to add an empty string - `''`. Then just use the `split` function to break the string into an array:

```
var Latitude = ((Math.floor(Math.random()*90) + Math.random()) + '').split('');
```

Comment: Very clever answer. Will accept when timelimit is up. Corrected the typo.

Answer (score 1):

```
var latitude = new Array();
latitude.value = Math.floor(Math.random*90) + Math.random();
latitude.push(2);//demonstrating that it's an array;
console.log(latitude.value);//for testing purposes only
console.log(latitude);//for testing purposes only
```

Now you can use latitude's value but also use it as an array.

***edit*** Sorry, I seem to have misread your question.  Graham's answer is correct.  But this might help someone with a similar problem.  I thought you wanted to use the same variable to store a value and an array.

Comment: This is also a clever answer, although Latitude has to remain a singular var, but I've now got two options for converting it.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the value first to string (toString()) and then split it (split()):

```
var arr = Latitude.toString().split('')
```